# One Kafka consumer in a group consistently rejects coordinator, but only when Spark and Kafka are both in EC2

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have a Java application trying to consume topics from a Kafka 2.5.1 cluster in EC2, using `spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11`. It works only from Spark clusters or standalone installs *outside* AWS: when Spark is also hosted in EC2, the Kafka consumer group never fully initializes. For three topics in all, only two consumers ever connect, while the third repeatedly rejects the group coordinator as "unavailable or invalid".

It is always the same third topic whose consumer fails, but the second and third topics are identically configured and both empty; the only difference between them is the name. Deleting and recreating the third topic does not change anything. Ignoring topic #3 in the application code (the first two can't easily be extricated) results in a successful startup.

All different Sparks are version 2.4.5, with the Google Guava JAR updated to 19.0 from the shipped 14.0.1, but no special configuration otherwise.

Kafka is a three-node EC2 cluster, with each node hosting a broker, a Zookeeper instance, and a Spark worker. Everything's talking and pingable from everything else. `server.properties` configures `listeners` to the *internal* DNS name, while `advertised.listeners` is the external.

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://ip-abc-def-ghi-jkl.region.compute.internal:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://ec2-mno-pqr-stu-vwx.region.compute.amazonaws.com:9092
```

The failing Spark application launch from inside EC2:

```
2020-10-08/21:09:32.694/UTC org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig INFO ConsumerConfig values:
        auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
        auto.offset.reset = latest
        bootstrap.servers = [ip-(broker 1 private dns).region.compute.internal:9092]
        check.crcs = true
        client.id =
        connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
        default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
        enable.auto.commit = false
        exclude.internal.topics = true
        fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
        fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
        fetch.min.bytes = 1
        group.id = mygroup
        heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
        interceptor.classes = []
        internal.leave.group.on.close = true
        isolation.level = read_uncommitted
        key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
        max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
        max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
        max.poll.records = 500
        metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.recording.level = INFO
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
        receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
        reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
        reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
        request.timeout.ms = 30000
        retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.jaas.config = null
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.login.class = null
        sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
        sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
        sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
        security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
        send.buffer.bytes = 131072
        session.timeout.ms = 10000
        ssl.cipher.suites = null
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
        ssl.key.password = null
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        ssl.protocol = TLS
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS
        value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer

2020-10-08/21:09:32.843/UTC org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser INFO Kafka version : 2.0.0
2020-10-08/21:09:32.844/UTC org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser INFO Kafka commitId : 3402a8361b734732
2020-10-08/21:09:33.098/UTC org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata INFO Cluster ID: mk34tRyzT1m1VR1ZC9GYnQ
2020-10-08/21:09:33.100/UTC org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=mygroup] Discovered group coordinator ec2-(broker 3 public dns).region.compute.amazonaws.com:9092 (id: 2147483644 rack: null)
2020-10-08/21:09:33.135/UTC org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=mygroup] Revoking previously assigned partitions []
2020-10-08/21:09:33.135/UTC org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=mygroup] (Re-)joining group
2020-10-08/21:09:39.155/UTC org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=mygroup] Successfully joined group with generation 1
2020-10-08/21:09:39.159/UTC org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=mygroup] Setting newly assigned partitions [partitions here]
2020-10-08/21:09:39.188/UTC org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=mygroup] Resetting offset for partition station-data-19 to offset 1976.

(more offset resets; consumer 2 has also joined the group successfully between 21:09:32 and 21:09:39. No activity from consumer 3 yet, unlike launches from an external Spark. Consumer 3 spin-up starts next)

2020-10-08/21:09:39.200/UTC org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser INFO Kafka version : 2.0.0
2020-10-08/21:09:39.205/UTC org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser INFO Kafka commitId : 3402a8361b734732
2020-10-08/21:09:39.213/UTC org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata INFO Cluster ID: mk34tRyzT1m1VR1ZC9GYnQ
2020-10-08/21:09:39.214/UTC org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=mygroup] Discovered group coordinator ec2-(broker 3 public dns).region.compute.amazonaws.com:9092 (id: 2147483644 rack: null)
2020-10-08/21:09:39.219/UTC org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=mygroup] Revoking previously assigned partitions []
2020-10-08/21:09:39.219/UTC org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=mygroup] (Re-)joining group
2020-10-08/21:09:42.268/UTC org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=mygroup] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
2020-10-08/21:09:42.268/UTC org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=mygroup] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing

(more heartbeat failures for consumers 1 and 2)

2020-10-08/21:10:09.254/UTC org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=mygroup] Group coordinator ec2-(broker 3 public dns).region.compute.amazonaws.com:9092 (id: 2147483644 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
2020-10-08/21:10:09.330/UTC org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=mygroup] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
2020-10-08/21:10:09.331/UTC org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=mygroup] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
2020-10-08/21:10:09.377/UTC org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=mygroup] Discovered group coordinator ec2-(broker 3 public dns).region.compute.amazonaws.com:9092 (id: 2147483644 rack: null)
```

With Spark outside EC2, this doesn't happen: all three consumers discover the coordinator and join the group more or less simultaneously, work out their offsets, and it's off to the races. But when the application is submitted to the Spark cluster in EC2, only the first two consumers join the group successfully. The third consumer doesn't start to initialize until after the first two have connected and reset their offsets, whereupon it discovers the group coordinator, tries to talk to it (causing a rebalance which prevents the other consumers from heartbeating), fails and decides it's invalid, and then finds the same coordinator again, repeat ad nauseam.

The only significant configuration difference between failing Spark submissions like this and successful Spark submissions from outside EC2 is that the latter `bootstrap.servers` have to point to brokers' external DNS names. However, the internal application launch fails whether it's pointed at brokers' external *or* internal names, one broker or multiple.

Here's the Kafka server.log from broker 3, identified above as the group coordinator:

```
[2020-10-08 21:09:33,128] INFO [GroupCoordinator 3]: Dynamic Member with unknown member id joins group mygroup in Empty state. Created a new member id consumer-2-cd4f7a30-d897-4902-81e7-4211b6a1e233 for this member and add to the group. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2020-10-08 21:09:33,128] INFO [GroupCoordinator 3]: Preparing to rebalance group mygroup in state PreparingRebalance with old generation 0 (__consumer_offsets-25) (reason: Adding new member consumer-2-cd4f7a30-d897-4902-81e7-4211b6a1e233 with group instance id None) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2020-10-08 21:09:33,136] INFO [GroupCoordinator 3]: Dynamic Member with unknown member id joins group mygroup in PreparingRebalance state. Created a new member id consumer-1-63909784-c821-4903-a08a-98a250d49b19 for this member and add to the group. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2020-10-08 21:09:39,128] INFO [GroupCoordinator 3]: Stabilized group mygroup generation 1 (__consumer_offsets-25) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2020-10-08 21:09:39,146] INFO [GroupCoordinator 3]: Assignment received from leader for group mygroup for generation 1 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2020-10-08 21:09:39,222] INFO [GroupCoordinator 3]: Dynamic Member with unknown member id joins group mygroup in Stable state. Created a new member id consumer-3-3a91c573-a90b-4b5c-9707-af285bf9bbac for this member and add to the group. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2020-10-08 21:09:39,222] INFO [GroupCoordinator 3]: Preparing to rebalance group mygroup in state PreparingRebalance with old generation 1 (__consumer_offsets-25) (reason: Adding new member consumer-3-3a91c573-a90b-4b5c-9707-af285bf9bbac with group instance id None) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)

... (more unknown member ids joining the group in PreparingRebalance)

[2020-10-08 21:14:37,756] INFO [GroupCoordinator 3]: Member consumer-2-cd4f7a30-d897-4902-81e7-4211b6a1e233 in group mygroup has failed, removing it from the group (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2020-10-08 21:14:37,757] INFO [GroupCoordinator 3]: Member consumer-1-63909784-c821-4903-a08a-98a250d49b19 in group mygroup has failed, removing it from the group (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2020-10-08 21:14:37,757] INFO [GroupCoordinator 3]: Stabilized group mygroup generation 2 (__consumer_offsets-25) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2020-10-08 21:14:39,625] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=3] Removed 0 expired offsets in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2020-10-08 21:14:47,758] INFO [GroupCoordinator 3]: Member consumer-3-057c4229-7183-4733-b973-9f758b9a69d0 in group mygroup has failed, removing it from the group (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2020-10-08 21:14:47,758] INFO [GroupCoordinator 3]: Preparing to rebalance group mygroup in state PreparingRebalance with old generation 2 (__consumer_offsets-25) (reason: removing member consumer-3-057c4229-7183-4733-b973-9f758b9a69d0 on heartbeat expiration) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2020-10-08 21:14:47,758] INFO [GroupCoordinator 3]: Member consumer-3-58c8ca8c-2daa-46c9-964b-7be883193287 in group mygroup has failed, removing it from the group (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)

... (more members failing and being removed)

[2020-10-08 21:14:47,759] INFO [GroupCoordinator 3]: Group mygroup with generation 3 is now empty (__consumer_offsets-25) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
```

Comment: Hi, do the heartbeat calls succeed when you start only two consumers?

Comment: Yes, if the third topic is skipped over the application starts successfully with two consumers for the first two topics.

Comment: Hi, I understand they start successfully, but are the heartbeats calls successful? Is there any chance that the consumers can not send heartbeats? Do you have a rule in the EC2 security group (or at the security level you use) that allows the Spark instance to make calls on the port 9093 to the Kafka cluster?

Comment: All Spark and Kafka instances are in a shared security group. A successful two-topic start doesn't log anything about heartbeats (at least at `INFO` level), which I take to be good news.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be the key:

> The third consumer doesn't start to initialize until after the first two have connected and reset their offsets

The first two consumers had a few seconds of no activity while consumer-3 spun up, after which the heartbeat failures started.

The Spark driver is an older instance (m3.large) with two vCPU cores. Our successful tests were from more recent machines with more cores, and when we restricted CPU availability with `taskset` on our test machines we were able to reproduce the problem exactly. Allowing `spark-submit` three cores succeeded.

This hadn't been an issue for us previously with the "simple" Kafka 0.8+ API, but getting started with the "new" Consumer API for 0.10+ seems to require a core per consumer in the group.

Comment: Good to know and glad you fixed it.